# How can I bulk insert with MongoDB (using PyMongo), even when one record of the bulk fails?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert

I have some **Python** code that uses `PyMongo` to insert many lists (of 1000 objects each), into a collection with a unique index (field name is `data_id`).

However, some of my lists of objects have duplicate data in the different sets of lists to be inserted (*e.g.*, perhaps the second list of 1000 objects has one or two records that are identical to some of the objects previously inserted in the first set of the bulk insert).

*Here's the problem*: when the code goes to bulk insert a set of 1000 objects, and one object has a previously inserted `data_id`, the entire insert for all 1000 object fails. I am performing the insert as below:

```
inserted = False
try:
    collection = self.db[self.database][self.collection]
    collection.insert(record)
    inserted = True

except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
    sys.stdout.write('Error connecting to %s: %s\n' % (self.connection_url, e))
except BaseException, e:
    sys.stdout.write('An error occurred in add_record: %s\n' % e)

return inserted
```

I have read somewhere (and now I can't find the reference anywhere!), that this can be avoided by telling Mongo the list is **unordered**. So I tried passing the insert line `ordered=False`, but this fails with:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ordered'
```

Does anyone know how to use `PyMongo.insert()` to unordered insert a list of objects so that only the non-unique records fail and the rest are inserted as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. For those interested, `.insert()` has been deprecated in `PyMongo` and it is advised to use `.insert_many()`, which respects the `ordered=False` keyword.