# Handling Failure in Bulk insertion in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, bulkinsert

Hi I need to insert around 100,000 records to mongodb. I am using BulkWriteOperation api to insert a batch of records. I split up the whole and inserting a batch of 1000 records to mongo. If any one of the record in a batchis failed to insert, then the whole batch is not being inserted to mongo. Is there anyway to get the list of records of the failed batch alone, so that i can do a recursive and insert the remaining records to mongo. Or is there any way to do bulk insert to mongodb and the all the records except the failed ones needs to be inserted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually set the batch size to 1 if there is a problem with some of the records. For 100,000 records the overhead of using a batch size of 1 instead of 1000 should be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The record size may grow to millions in future.using the batch insert is better right?

Answer (score 0):

Could you also make sure to mention which language you are using?

In case of python, I found that using the [insert_many](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) operation with ordered=False is better for this use case (This will only work if the ordering of your inserts don't matter - as required, it will not fail if some of the inserts fail). The BulkWriteError gives the details of the inserts that have failed and you can use the error code to decide what to do afterwards.

It should work similarly for other languages. Do let me know if it doesn't work.
Edit: This question seems similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615414/how-can-i-bulk-insert-with-mongodb-using-pymongo-even-when-one-record-of-the?rq=1)